# how to use scapy to decode H2C message

Tags: scapy, http2

scapy has a module named http2, and in its information: "encode/decode HTTP/2 Frames"

```py
import scapy.contrib.http2 as http2
packets = rdpcap("in.pcapng")
for p in packets:
    if p.haslayer(TCP):
        p[TCP].payload # how to turn this into a http2.H2Seq or http2.H2Frame??
```

`p[TCP].payload.name` gives "raw", and `p.haslayer(http2.H2Seq)` or `http2.H2Frame` gives false.

I would like to turn this packet into a http2 one, and then parse headers or data if any.

Comment: can you upload the pcap file you are trying to read? Are the http2 packets use TLS too?

Comment: @Shir It is H2C not H2, so TLS is not used. i don't have the pcap at hand, but scapy can generate a H2C message. So you could use scapy generate a H2C message (it is well documented on their website).

Comment: I couldn't find a solution, but you can find a pcap here- https://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP2